# How to bind array parameter for filtering with IN operator in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need to bind parameter that contains list of values and then use it in the query for filtering with `IN` operator. Assume we have following schema:

```
create table test_table (
    id  serial primary key,
    channel text
);

insert into test_table(channel) values ('FOO'), ('BAR'), ('BAZ');
```

Basically the query acts like:

```
select * from test_table
where channel in ('FOO', 'BAR');
```

But I need to pass the channels array dynamically. I've tried:

```
select * from test_table
where channel in (string_to_array('FOO, BAR', ',')::text[]);

ERROR: operator does not exist: text = text[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 42
```

So my question is: how to use string_to_array for `IN` operator?
Or how to bind array parameter to the query and use it for `IN`?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab47a/13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`= any`:

```
where channel = any (string_to_array('FOO, BAR', ',')::text[]);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21108

Comment: He solved it from a different perspective. You're a savior. Cheers.